# org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jetty.plus

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, osgi-fragment

from Karaf cache log i have receive the following error multiple times when i'm deploy bundle in karaf

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jetty.jndi 4 0 2019-02-21 16:27:11.500
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jetty.jndi [77]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.mail; version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 1):

The bundle `org.eclipse.jetty.jndi` has dependency on `javax.mail; version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)"`. There are 2 reasons for this error here.

1. None of the Bundle is exporting the `javax.mail` or host didn't add package `javax.mail` as SYSTEM_PACKAGE.
2. The host has added `javax.mail` as SYSTEM_PACKAGE but the version might not lie between 1.4.0 and 2.0.0.

P.S : The host here is Equinox

Comment: `javax.mail` is not a package defined by the Java SE standard and therefore is not exported by default from the OSGi system bundle.

Comment: Yes, only java.* packages are exported by default. Any other packages apart from `java.*` should be exported explicitly.

Comment: No that's not correct. The framework also exports standard Java SE packages under the `javax` namespace such as `javax.xml.bind`. The point is, `javax.mail` is not a Java SE standard package and it is not shipped with any edition of the JDK.